# Student-Teacher matching problem

Tags: classification, recommender-system

The problem I want to solve is as follows:
I have data about how many teaching hours different students spend with their teacher in order to pass their exams. The teaching varies from 25-55 hours. In the school there are approximately 15 teachers and given a set of 10 student-teacher features that describe personality characteristics such as, age, sex, education, nationality, etc., I want to develop a student-teacher match model in order to minimize the teaching hours a student needs to pass the exams.

Any idea of what sort of algorithms I should use, or any examples I can look at?

Comment: Maybe for Clarification. Do you envision this as a Classification or as a Minimization Problem: Do you want to find the ideal solution for the current data or do you want to be able to predict it for, lets say, future students?

Comment: Thanks @ElBurro. I think it's a classification problem and yes I want to predict what is the best student-teacher match for incoming future students.

Comment: Are there any boundary conditions (student/ teacher ratio-  do you want to find the solution that is best for everyone together or rather the solution that is best for one student?)

Comment: I'd like the system to recommend top 3-5 candidate teachers for a new, incoming student. No more conditions. The data I have is pairs of student/teachers and how many teaching hours needed for a specific student with a specific teacher to pass the exams

Comment: Can they also fail or is this only about minimum time spend teaching? Is the time dependent on the class or individual for each student-teacher-subject set?

Comment: If they fail they take more classes, hence more teaching hours which is not good. Classes are individual one student-one teacher. I'm just looking for opinions on good ML algorithm candidates for the problem.

Comment: How many students do you have in your existing dataset?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a recommendation problem. You can find a nice overview [here](https://medium.com/recombee-blog/machine-learning-for-recommender-systems-part-1-algorithms-evaluation-and-cold-start-6f696683d0ed).

Comment: Thanks @ElBurro